# SharePoint changing statistics options daily

Tags: sql-server, statistics, error-log, sharepoint

SharePoint switches `OFF` and `ON` options like `AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS`, `AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC`, `AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS`,  `INCREMENTAL` on SharePoint databases daily at 12 AM and that generates lots of noise in SQL Server error log.

What action should I take(Either in SQL Server or in SharePoint)  to keep the error log clean?

Comment: Ignore or filter-out the messages you don't care about?

Comment: There are no settings in SQL Server to stop specific log messages from being written to the error log.  You might want to check to see if there is a setting in SharePoint to stop it from making these changes.

Comment: I check the error log of all the instances once everyday and some times I overlook critical events in the log because of so much noise as there is no visual indication between informational, warning and critical. In filter there is no option to exclude and once you close the windows all filter settings are lost.